# Inno Setup - How to prevent it from asking the user if he wants to create a desktop shortcut

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to create an installer and I have come across this issue.

I cannot tell Inno to skip the page where it asks the user if he wants to create a desktop shortcut.

I have removed my entire [Icons] section (just in case) and nothing changed.

I have searched some of the [Setup] settings and I don't see any relevant:

```
DisableStartupPrompt=Yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=Yes
DisableReadyPage=Yes
DisableWelcomePage=Yes
DisableFinishedPage=Yes
DisableDirPage=Yes
```

Now, I really don't understand how it choses an EXE to create a link for but the created link seems to do nothing.

Is there any way to skip this installer screen and not create a shortcut at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I have found the solution.

I hadn't noticed that there was a section called `[Tasks]` having this code:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
```

When removing it, everything is the way I want it.